# Problems with JSF datatable and Bootsfaces modal windows

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootsfaces

I am using JSF for my webapp (combined with EJB) and Bootsfaces as JavaScript addition to show modal windows. I am having a list of items that are being shown through a dataTable. And by clicking on a command button inside my list I am opening a modal window, asking the user "wether he is sure he wants to delete". That modal confirm dialog has YES and NO. I can execute the yes execute button inside the modal window. But I cant do #{controller.delete(item)} because the item is only server side available while building the list table. Somehow I have to send the actual selected item to the modal window to set it somehow in that controller call...???

Anyone got an idea?

```
<!-- looping the jsf list //-->
<h:dataTable value="#{controller.itemlist}" var="item"...
...
<!-- showing modal window //-->
<h:commandButton value="delete" action="" onClick="return false;" p:toggle-data.... />
</h:dataTable>
</h:form>
...
<!-- modal window in panel, with item not set //-->
...
<h:commandButton action="#{controller.delete(item)}" />
</h:form>
</b:panel>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ajax to populate your modal's content :

```
$.ajax({
    url : "yourPage.jsf",
    type : "POST",
    data : {
        id: "your object's id"
    },
    dataType : "html"
}).done(function(html) {
    $("#yourModal").html(html);
});
```

This ajax should be called with `onclick` event on your `<h:commandButton>`

And of course, you'd need to create a JSF view for your modal content. This view will contain your text and your two buttons "Yes" and "No". "No" should just dismiss your modal, while "Yes" should call your bean action : `<h:commandButton action="#{controller.delete(item)}" />`.

Don't forget to populate your controller `item` with the `id` parameter to bind data to your view.

**EDIT :**

I'll try to show you an example.

Main View (view.xhtml) :

```
<h:form>
  <h:dataTable value="#{controller.itemlist}" var="item">

    <h:column>
     ...
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
      <h:commandButton value="delete" onclick="return populateModal(#{item.id}); " />
    </h:column>

  </h:dataTable>

</h:form>
```

Script to populate your modal (view.xhtml) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function populateModal(id) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "view2.jsf",
      type: "POST",
      data: { id: id },
      dataType: "html"
    }).done(function(html) {
      $("#modal").html(html);
      $("#modal").show();
    });

    return false;
  }
</script>
```

Then you need a view for your modal's content (view2.xhtml) :

```
<h:form>

  Delete #{testBean2.item.name} ?
  <h:commandButton value="YES" action="#{testBean2.delete(testBean2.item)}" />
  <h:commandButton value="NO" onclick="return closeModal();" />

</h:form>
```

And a controller for this view (testBean2.java) :

```
private Item item;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    // GET id parameter from HTTPRequest
    // Populate Local Item
}

public void delete(Item item) {
    // Delete your item
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I only know about JSF and formating my xhtml page with bootstrap. But i am no expert in JQuery so far. I can give it a try and play around. But I dont know anything about .done(function... or $.ajax etc.

Comment: @Arquillian $.ajax() and .done() : [link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). This is pretty straightforward, you make an ajax call to a second view to generate your modal's html, passing the current item id. Then from this view, you create a button to dismiss your modal and another one to submit a form calling a bean action.

Comment: well i tried a whole week now, i never spent so much time on a problem without finding the correct solution in my whole life... i played around with self written javascript, with jsf actionlisteners, bootsfaces features .... i am giving up on it. i dont think you can do this with jsf and bootsfaces:

Comment: the problem is you cant transport the foreach item from the datatable to the backing bean to use it later in the bootsfaces modal again.

Comment: @Arquillian See updated answer. You can also search `<f:ajax>` for a more simple version.

Comment: Thx @Thrax for the example! I will try it out within the next days. Maybe it will not get into the release version. But one of the next versions would be great too. There is always space for improvements ;)

Comment: Accepted this answer to solve the question. But I am not working with JSF anymore. And I cant guarantee that it works, I didnt get this solved.